# Swift - Adding touch to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, navigationbar

I'm following a tutorial online and I'm trying to add touch detection to an `UIImageView`. I realize that this can be done with a gesture recognizer but I have a different problem and I don't know how to ask for it.

Basically, I added an overlay `UIButton` initialized from the frame of imageView. However, I have to move the frame down 64 px because of the navigation bar. My imageView is added form the storyboard but `UIButton` is added programmatically.

Is there a way to do this without adding 64 px manually? This is no biggies but since the frame of the imageView when printing is `(10, 10, 355, 450)` and the frame of `UIButton` is `(10, 74, 355, 450)`, it kinda ticks me off a little bit.

Let me clarify, I'm wondering why view controller doesn't take into account the size of the navigation bar when adding subview programmatically? It seems to handle this just fine when adding subview from Storyboard.

[Without adding 64px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUZCC.png):

```
    overlay = UIButton(frame: imageView.frame)
    overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    overlay.addTarget(self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(overlay)
```

[With 64px added - fits perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEjR4.png)

```
    overlay = UIButton(frame: imageView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 64))
    overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    overlay.addTarget(self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(overlay)
```

Comment: Could you show the attributes inspectors capture of your UIViewController?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't add more than 2 links right now but everything is set to default settings with size: inferred, status bar: inferred, top bar: inferred and bottom bar: inferred.

Comment: You can use self.view.frame as given in answer please check the answer.

Comment: If the imageView displayed correct, try to add overlay as a subView of imageView instead of self.view.

Comment: I should mention that the imageView is added from the storyboard with navigation controller embedded. However, I want to add an instance of UIButton to overlay to imageview but I have to add 64px manually

Comment: The problem is obviously that your `imageView` is lying in the different superview.

Comment: Your right!!!!!!! Hahahaha I would mark your comment correct if I could

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add button on image view.

Try This :

```
let overlay = UIButton(frame: imageView.bounds)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        overlay.addTarget(self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        imageView.addSubview(overlay)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the same as given below.

```
    let bg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Home"))
    bg.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(bg)

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SecondViewController.onTapScreen))
    bg.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    bg.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Handle tap event as given below

```
    func onTapScreen() {
         // Handle touch here.
    }
```

By this way you don't need to use button also so it can avoid multiple controls.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `UIViewController`'s navigationbar to `Opaque Navigation Bar`. It will start you view below navigation bar.

[image]